# Add lower labels to highstock control

Tags: highcharts

Currently lower part of my highstock control looks like this:
[image]

How can I add lower labels to this control, so it looks like this?

[image]

I don't use rangeSelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `navigator xAxis formatter` for labels:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/PsUYc/

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.xAxis